# How do you display a Applet in a Jpanel java

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, mixing

```
package net.rstown;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AppletContext;
import java.applet.AppletStub;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RS2Loader extends JFrame implements AppletStub {

    public static final String PAGE_ADDRESS = "http://oldschool1.runescape.com/";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3450697819043722786L;
    private static final HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private static URL pageAddressUrl;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    pageAddressUrl = new URL(PAGE_ADDRESS);
    String pageSource = readPageSource(PAGE_ADDRESS);
    parseParameters(pageSource);
    String gamepackFileName = findGamepackFileName(pageSource);
    URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL(
        PAGE_ADDRESS + gamepackFileName) });
    Applet game = (Applet) classLoader.loadClass("client").newInstance();
    RS2Loader rs2Loader = new RS2Loader();
    game.setStub(rs2Loader);
    game.init();
    game.start();
    rs2Loader.add(game);
    rs2Loader.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    rs2Loader.setSize(773, 530);
    rs2Loader.setTitle("Old School RuneScape Client Loader");
    rs2Loader.setResizable(false);
    rs2Loader.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static String readPageSource(String pageAddress) throws IOException {
    String source = "";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new URL(pageAddress).openStream());
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        source += scanner.nextLine() + "\n";
    }
    scanner.close();
    return source;
    }

    private static void parseParameters(String pageSource) {
    String[] lines = pageSource.split("\n");
    String paramNameBeginning = "param name=";
    String valueBeginning = "value=";
    for (String line : lines) {
        if (!line.contains(paramNameBeginning)) {
        continue;
        }
        int start = line.indexOf(paramNameBeginning)
            + paramNameBeginning.length() + 1;
        int end = line.indexOf('"', start);
        String name = line.substring(start, end);
        start = line.indexOf(valueBeginning) + valueBeginning.length() + 1;
        end = line.indexOf('"', start);
        String value = line.substring(start, end);
        parameters.put(name, value);
    }
    }

    private static String findGamepackFileName(String pageSource) {
    String gamepackFileNameStart = "archive=";
    int gamepackFileNameStartIndex = pageSource
        .indexOf(gamepackFileNameStart);
    return pageSource.substring(gamepackFileNameStartIndex
        + gamepackFileNameStart.length(),
        pageSource.indexOf('\'', gamepackFileNameStartIndex));
    }

    public URL getDocumentBase() {
    return pageAddressUrl;
    }

    public URL getCodeBase() {
    return pageAddressUrl;
    }

    public String getParameter(String name) {
    return parameters.get(name);
    }

    public AppletContext getAppletContext() {
    return null;
    }

    public void appletResize(int width, int height) {

    }
}`
```

Thats the loader class and a picture of it is here http://prntscr.com/yin89
Botwindow which is the Jpanel is where i want the loader to be display a picture of the botwindow when i open it is here http://prntscr.com/yin29.

```
   package net.rstown.gui;


import net.rstown.RS2Loader;
import net.rstown.log.Loggable;
import net.rstown.log.TextAreaLogHandler;
import net.rstown.menu.Menu;
import net.rstown.util.Configuration;
import net.rstown.util.Resources;



import javax.swing.*;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AppletContext;
import java.awt.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public final class BotWindow extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("BotWindow");

    private static boolean slowGraphics;

    public static boolean useSlowGraphics() {
        return slowGraphics;
    }

    private static final BotWindow instance = new BotWindow().initialize();

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        super.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        super.setVisible(visible);
    }

    public static final BotWindow get() {
        return instance;
    }

    private final JScrollPane TEXT_SCROLL = new JScrollPane(22, 31);

    public JScrollPane getLogScrollPane() {
        return TEXT_SCROLL;
    }
//  private LoadingScreen screen = new LoadingScreen();
   private RS2Loader loader = new RS2Loader();


    private BotWindow initialize() {

        setSize(768, 530);
        setIconImage(Resources.Images.ICON);
        setTitle(Configuration.NAME + (Configuration.OUTDATED ? " (outdated)" : "") + (Configuration.DEVMODE ? " (developer mode)" : ""));
        Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(new TextAreaLogHandler());
        log.info("Welcome to RsTown!");
        Loggable.devlog("RsTown", "You are in developer mode!");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        TEXT_SCROLL.setViewportView(TextAreaLogHandler.TEXT_AREA);
        TEXT_SCROLL.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(765, Configuration.DEVMODE ? 120 : 19));
        setJMenuBar(BotMenu.get());
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());  
        add(TEXT_SCROLL, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //setSize(775, Configuration.DEVMODE ? 672 : 573);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(775, Configuration.DEVMODE ? 672 : 573));
        add(loader, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //add(screen, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // add(BotToolBar.get(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getContentPane());
        setLocationCentered();
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);

        return this;
    }




    /*public void removeLoadingScreen() {
        if (screen == null) return;
        remove(screen);
        screen = null;
        setResizable(true);
    }*/




    private void setLocationCentered() {
        final int x = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width / 2 - this.getWidth() / 2;
        final int y = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height / 2 - this.getHeight() / 2;
        setLocation(x, y);
    }

    public void toggleLog() {
        final boolean small = TEXT_SCROLL.getHeight() == 19;
        Menu.LOG_PLANE_TOGGLE.setIcon(new ImageIcon(small ? Resources.Images.HIDE_LOG : Resources.Images.SHOW_LOG));
        TEXT_SCROLL.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(TEXT_SCROLL.getWidth(), small ? 120 : 19));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(775, small ? 672 : 573));
        if (!small) {
            setSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight() - 99));
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int lastIndex = TextAreaLogHandler.TEXT_AREA.getModel().getSize() - 1;
                if (lastIndex >= 0) {
                    TextAreaLogHandler.TEXT_AREA.ensureIndexIsVisible(lastIndex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static final class LoadingScreen extends JComponent {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public LoadingScreen() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(707, 500));
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(Resources.Images.LOADING_IMAGE, 0, 0, null);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the AppletWindow class that you can download here:
http://www.bluej.org/resources/classes.html#appletwindow